# What happens when memory is full in a node?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, nodes, memory

I am using go-ethereum and running a private blockchain network. I want to what is supposed to happen when the memory is full in the nodes. Will the program stop abruptly or will the old blocks get deleted?

Comment: Ram or disk space?

Comment: I suppose if ram is full, a virtual memory from hard disk will be created. So what if hard disk also is full?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely old blocks will not get deleted, but new blocks will not get added to the Chaindata in local.